# Insertion stored procedure values in java not get stored in sql table

Tags: java, stored-procedures

Joined: Jun 07, 2010
Posts: 1

[Post New]posted Today 12:53:46 AM
Quote Edit
Help me,

AM using struts2 frame work, am sending the values to db method and i have written code, my try block executed no err msg in console, I get the msg Stored procedure exe succ, but my values are not get insert into table. In sql stored procedure 4 input params and 4 output param has been given. I get values in debug mode for the values for input params, which i get that form bean, but not for output params, here with i add my code please help me with this bug.

```
package db;

import java.util.List;
import java.sql.*;

import hbsbean.AddNewFieldsBean;

public class ApplicationStoredDB {
    public List<AddNewFieldsBean> storeNewRecords(AddNewFieldsBean bean) {
        List<AddNewFieldsBean> nbean = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        String jdbcDriver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        String dbURL = "jdbc: odbc:sqlserver";
        String usernameDbConn = "root";
        String passwordDbConn = "hbsroot";
        try {
            Class.forName(jdbcDriver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, usernameDbConn,
                    passwordDbConn);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("jdbc driver not found:" + dbURL);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // make a callable statement for a stored procedure.

            CallableStatement cstmt = conn
                    .prepareCall("{call proc_application_menu(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,?)}");

            // set the values of the stored procedure's input parameters

            System.out.println("calling stored procedure . . .");
            for (int i = 0; i < bean.getAppName().length; i++) {

                cstmt.setString(1, bean.getAppName()[i]);
                cstmt.setString(2, bean.getBasepath()[i]);
                cstmt.setString(3, bean.getDesc()[i]);
                cstmt.setString(4, bean.getUsername());

                // output params in sql
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(5, Types.INTEGER);
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(6, Types.INTEGER);
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(7, Types.VARCHAR);
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(8, Types.VARCHAR);
                cstmt.execute();
            }
            // now that the input parameters are set, we can proceed to execute
            // the insertTheForm stored procedure

            cstmt.close();
            System.out.println("Stored procedure executed succesfully.....");
        }

        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("error: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return nbean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edited after rereading the question:

The execute would not get called if getAppName().length was zero. Could this be the case?